# vue.js unit test that html content does not exist

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

Using vue test utils, I'm unable to find in the docs how to test that html/text is not rendered. For example, to test that html text is rendered we can use

```
expect(wrapper.html()).toContain('Some specific placeholder')
```

How can I test that this string 'Some specific placeholder' is not rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll be better using `text` instead of `html`, in that way your current test would be:

```
expect(wrapper.text()).toBe('Some specific placeholder')
```

and the one checking for no rendered text can be like this:

```
expect(wrapper.text()).toBe('')
```

or

```
expect(wrapper.text()).not.toBe('Some specific placeholder')
```

depending on your specific scenario.